# How to clear cache dynamically on JSONLoader in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, browser-cache

I created one threejs application, which is loaded number of models using JSONLoader. Whenever I called Jsonloader it increases browser cache, I Attached images for verification. When browser cache increased to 10MB, mobile browser crashed. I want to clear my cache at every Jsonloader call completed. I thought it is one of the solution. I need help on how to clear cache on Jsonloader or other solutions.

**First call**

[image: On first call image]

**Second call**

[image: On second call image]